# Manage accounts in Remix Web3 Provider env connected to a TestRPC client node

Tags: truffle, remix, testrpc, ganache, web3-providers

When I run the TestRPC client (ganache-cli), it provides me with 10 different accounts and private keys along with a local server at localhost:8545

> ## Available Accounts
>
> (0) 0x6b499615fb839b33ffd9cea1380727a7ee0c39b1
>
> ...
>
> (9) 0x8ff593ecc3f4068ff15bffe4481ec627e7cd8247
>
> ## Private Keys
>
> (0) cb7eba4cef5a7a1ad16b30e7b380b38a1d23fc52aaebed77d5c53d4b7133cd6c
>
> ...
>
> (9) 9a64d0bbadbf1873657ecf02b7c0b926cef1fdde34283478ef7973473f339537
>
> ## HD Wallet
>
> Mnemonic:      ordinary husband nation coast above benefit hamster kitchen fantasy check notice hobby Base HD Path: 
>   m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
>
> Listening on localhost:8545

Now, in Remix when I change the environment to Web3 Provider and connect to localhost:8545, the box Account gets emptied and I'm forced to create a new account assigning a passphrase to it. It does not let me choose any of the above accounts created automatically by TestRPC.

[image]

The problem is that this new account created by Remix has a balance of 0 so it doesn't let me deploy a smart contract or do anything else.

How can I pick in Remix one from the 10 accounts created by TestRPC or how can I transfer some ether from one of these accounts to the account created by Remix in order to deploy a smart contract and make other transactions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This normally just works, populating the "Account" dropdown with the existing accounts. (I just tried it now.) What version of  `ganache-cli` are you running? And you said "localhost:8545", but you're using an HTTP URL, right? E.g. "http://localhost:8545"

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @smarx I should mention that I installed Ethereumjs-testrpc (npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc) instead of ganache-cli (I'm new at this and didn't know TestRPC is being deprecated). Do you think that contributed to the problem?... Version: EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2). The endpoint I'm connecting to is http : // localhost:8545, although when I go to that localhost through a chrome browser it only shows "400 Bad Request", is this normal?... The error that throws the JS console is "Error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 278786  and the send.."

Comment: I would definitely start by uninstalling that old version and installing the latest `ganache-cli` instead. My guess is that the problem will just go away.

Comment: @smarx thanks for the suggestion. It worked. If you want you can post it as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

try localhost 7545 instead of 8545...it will connect the RPC server to remix